# Azure AD authentication environments

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I have the following problem, I have an application in Angular where I use MSAL 2.0 that allows to use the Azure AD authentication service, is there any way to separate the development, testing and production environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **To create Azure AD authentication for multiple environments, please try the following:**

- In Azure portal, try creating ***separate App registrations*** for development, testing and production environments.
- Based on your application configuration select the required (same or separate) redirect URLs.
- To reduce complexity, keep app registrations separate for all the environments.

**Otherwise**, create one App Registration and use that same ***applicationID*** and ***applicationSecret*** and Redirect URL in all the other environments.

Try creating of ***separate Directories*** for different environments and then have the app registration in each of these directories.

To know how to register an application in Azure portal, please **refer** below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application.

For more information in detail, please **refer** the below link:

[Azure AD Authentication for same application in multiple environment - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/32034/azure-ad-authentication-for-same-application-in-mu.html).